# Parent displaying the title and other metadata of a child

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have a main component which provides common elements for all views in my app:

```
var Main = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div id="main">
         <MenuBar title={this.state.title} icon={this.state.title} />
         <div id="view">{React.Children.only(this.props.children)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Then I could use it like this:

```
<Main>{router.routeComponent(path)}</Main>
```

Now, I would like the title property (and possibly other "meta" information about the child) of the menu bar be set by the child view in this case. My current idea for this is to have child views expose a `.getMetadata()` method and a `onMetadataChanged={...}` property and then have the child return an object like `{ title: "Foobar", icon: "images/foobar.png" }` from the `getMetadata()` method.

A second option would be to repeat the Main component for every view like this:

```
var SomeView = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Main title="Some view" icon="images/foobar.png">
        {/* view content here */}
      </Main>
    );
  }
});
```

However, the disadvantage of this, if I understand correctly, is that the performance will be worse when switching view since React will not try to merge the DOM tree if the `SomeView` component changes to an entirely different component (i.e. `SomeOtherView`). This would mean that all of DOM nodes of `Main` would have to be recreated.

What would the idiomatic/best way be to do this in React?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be an event emitter.  You could also use flux if you're already using it.

```js
var emitter = new (require('events').EventEmitter); // or from http://wzrd.in/standalone/events

var Main = React.createClass({

  // apply the metadata to state when the event is emitted
  componentDidMount: function(){
    emitter.on('site-metadata', this.handleMetadata);
  },

  handleMetadata: function(meta){ 
    this.setState({title: meta.title, icon: meta.icon}); 
  },
  // in willUnmount remove the listener

  render: function() {
    // ...
  }
});

router.provideSiteMetadata = function(meta){
  Object.assign(router.meta, meta);
  emitter.emit('site-metadata', router.meta);
};
router.meta = {title: '', icon: null};
```

You then call `router.provideSiteMetadata`, and any components interested in this metadata will be notified, and can apply it to state.

Comment: This is a nice solution if there is actually one main component, but let's say we have multiple views that can have a title which depends on the content?

Comment: You can pass callbacks down as props instead of using event emitters, or have an audience property of the event payload, where most listeners ignore the event if the audience doesn't match them, or use flux.  There are more variables in that situation, but I don't really understand where it'd come up, so I'm not sure what the best solution is.

Comment: The answer together with your above comment constitutes an acceptable answer to me :)